# $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^{n+1}, & x \text{ irrational}\\ 0, & x \text{ rational}\end{cases}$ is differentiable at $0$ and discontinuous at $x\neq 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, continuity

I have proved that

> For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the function
> $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^{n+1}, & x \text{ irrational}\\ 
>                    0, & x \text{ rational}\end{cases}$ is differentiable at $0$ and discontinuous at every $x\neq 0$.

but I am not sure about the correctness of my proof, especially the last part, where I show that it is discontinuous at every non-zero rational number, so I would appreciate if someone would check it out. I welcome comments. Thanks

Proof. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $h\neq 0$.

$|\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}|\leq|\frac{h^{n+1}}{h}|=|h|^{n}\xrightarrow{h\to 0}0$ so $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=0$ thus $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=0.$

Suppose $a$ is irrational and take $\varepsilon:=\frac{|a|^{n+1}}{2}$. Then, since the rationals are dense in the reals, we have that however we choose $\delta>0$ there exists $x_q\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)\setminus\{a\}\cap\mathbb{Q}$ such that $|f(x_q)-f(a)|=|0-a^{n+1}|=|a|^{n+1}>\varepsilon$ so $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)\neq f(a)$ i.e. $f$ is not continuous at $a$.

Suppose now that $a$ is a non-zero rational number. Pick $|a|>d>0$ and set $\ell:=\inf\{|f(x)|:x\in (a-d,a+d)\setminus\{a\}\cap\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\}$. Then if we take $\varepsilon:=\frac{\ell}{2}$ we have that for every $\delta>0$ there exists some $x_p\in (a-d,a+d)\setminus\{a\}\cap (a-\delta,a+\delta)\setminus\{a\}$ such that $|f(x_p)-f(a)|=|f(x_p)|>\varepsilon$, so $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)\neq f(a)$ i.e. $f$ is not continuous at $a$. $\square$

Comment: $|\frac{h^{n+1}}h|=|h|^n$, not $|h|^{n+1}$.

Comment: This looks good. There's a typo in inequality for differentiability at $0$ when you simplify $$
\biggl\lvert \frac{h^{n+1}}{h} \biggr\rvert
$$

Comment: @AnneBauval Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Your choice of $\ell$ works only if $a>0$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks! I have modified the definition of $\ell$ and now it should work. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes but why not take simply $\ell=|a|^{n+1}$ (and not pick any $d$)?